# How to check more than one year in 'leap year'

Tags: c#

Just recently started learning C# and did in class the 'leap year'. We came up with this solution. But it only allows to check one year at a time. Is there a nice way to check more at once? Let's say I need to check 10 different years if they are leap or not. All I could think of is copying the block and giving new variable.

```
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

bool div1 = a % 4 == 0;
bool div2 = a % 100 != 0; 
bool div3 = a % 400 == 0;

if ((div1 && div2) || div3)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{a} is a leap year");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{a} is not a leap year");
}
```

Comment: Have you learned what a `for` loop is?

Comment: I understand you wrote this for a class exercise, but please know that in the real world, you would be expected to use the `DateTime.IsLeapYear` built-in function.  I would not let any code review pass by me that used hand-crafted leap-year checking.

Comment: Not yet. I might be running a bit ahead. But it's a bit uncomfortable to run everything from start if  you want to check another random year. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to write a function that takes in an int and returns `true` if the int represents a leap year. For example, the method below uses a simplified, one-line version of the code you wrote above:

```
public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
{
    return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0;
}
```

Then, you can get a bunch of years from the user (in this example we're using a comma-separated list of years), split the years into an array (on the comma character), and call this method for each year in a loop:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Get a list of years from the user
    Console.Write("Enter some years separated by commas: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    // Split the user input on the comma character, creating an array of years
    var years = input.Split(',');

    foreach (var year in years)
    {
        bool isLeapYear = IsLeapYear(int.Parse(year));

        if (isLeapYear)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is a leap year", year);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a leap year", year);
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Another thing you can do, if you want to enter them one at a time, is just ask the user for a new year inside a loop, and give them the answer after they enter an integer. Here's an example, where I also added another function called `GetIntFromUser`, which forces them to enter a valid integer (it keeps asking until one is entered):

```
private static void Main()
{
    // In this loop, ask for a year and tell them the answer
    while (true)
    {
        int input = GetIntFromUser("Enter a year to check: ");
        string verb = IsLeapYear(input) ? "is" : "is not";
        Console.WriteLine($"{input} {verb} a leap year.\n");
    }
}

public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int input;

    // Show the prompt and keep looping until the input is a valid integer
    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}

public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
{
    return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you put the existing code into a function, so it can be re-used:

```
public bool IsLeapYear(int year)
{
    bool div1 = year % 4 == 0;
    bool div2 = year % 100 != 0; 
    bool div3 = year % 400 == 0;
    return ((div1 && div2) || div3);
}
```

Then let's say you have a set of 40 years in an array:

```
//don't worry about how this works right now.
// just know it gives you an array with 40 years starting in 1980
int[] years = Enumerable.Range(1980, 40).ToArray();
```

You can check all of them like this:

```
foreach (int year in years)
{
    if (IsLeapYear(year))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{year} is a leap year");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{year} is not a leap year");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ.

```
var years = new int[] { 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002 };  //etc...

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, years
    .Select(y => $"{y} {(DateTime.IsLeapYear(y) ? "is" : "is not")} a leap year")
    .ToArray()));
```

Comment: This works... but it's not a very useful answer in the context of the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a string of years (e.g.: `1991,1992,2001,2004`), then split the string to array with `string.split(',')`. Loop through the array to check for leap year.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using int.Parse(), you should use it in try-catch block. Otherwise your program will crash everytime when user enters nonsense.

Second, if you want to implement your own method for studying purposes - it`s okay, but you can use DateTime structure, which has IsLeapYear():

```
    // Summary:
    //     Returns an indication whether the specified year is a leap year.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   year:
    //     A 4-digit year.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if year is a leap year; otherwise, false.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
    //     year is less than 1 or greater than 9999.
```

So, the implementation is:

```
class LeapYear
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int input = 0; input < 10;) // Ask user until he enters year 10 times correctly
        {

            Console.Write("Please enter a year: ");

            try
            {
                int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{year} is leap");
                    input++;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"{year} is not leap");
            }

            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Argument Out Of Range");
            }

            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bad Format");
            }

            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Overflow");
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```